# vim how to using jk to move page down up without touch to the bottom or top

Tags: vim

In ubuntu 17.04, the vim using `jk` to move page down up without touch to the bottom or top, like following gif screen record:

how to do the same on OSX[image]

Comment: In Vim? All vim shortcuts are the same across platforms.

Comment: @ifconfig, Yes, I know that, The problem is I do not know know how to config vim to achieve above animation on OSX

Comment: What animation?

Comment: sorry, I lost the gif image when first post and then I updated my question again @ifconfig

Comment: I am still confused what you are talking about. The black key highlight?

Comment: No, @Eric Leung answered, You can refresh the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.vimrc`, you can add the following

```
set so=7 " sets 7 lines up/down of cursor when moving vertically
```

`so` stands for "scrolloff". So you can set how many lines you want to buffer. Default is 5 lines up and down. You can learn more at `:help 'scrolloff'`.